# "Head Office" in Esperanto

Tags: single-word-requests

One can find many variations of "head office" in Esperanto. For example, from Tekstaro, Wikipedia, Tatoeba, Glosbe etc., we can find:

- ĉefoficejo
- ĉefa oficejo
- ĉefsidejo
- centra sidejo
- socia sidejo
- centra administrejo

I am looking for the right expression for the head office of a company, a corporation.

Are they all correct? Which expression do you see most often?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UEA uses the term [*centra oficejo*](https://uea.org/asocio), but I would say, that there is not a single right term (whatever that means here), rather a bunch to choose among. Having said that I find *socia* and *sidejo* here a little odd, so I would choose between:

- *centra oficejo*: central office
- *ĉefa oficejo* : main office
- *centra administrejo* : central administration